# Getting DataTables in tree diagram form from a single DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, system.data

I have a DataTable that contains following columns: type,name,year,version. I want DataTables that contain unique combinations. The table is first divided into multiple tables that have unique name+year combinations. 
Those tables need to be split again into tables with a unique type. There are a total of 4 types, and 8 different combinations of name + year. So I'm trying to extract a total of 64 Datatables from a single Datatable.

I've tried to first get the distinct combinations of name + year. I've added them to a list(class containing name and Datatable) and if a row from the original table contains that combination i add it to a new DataTable.

```
DataTable distinctTable = table.DefaultView.ToTable(true, new string[] { name,year });

foreach(var combo in distinctTable) 
{
        complexlist.add(new ComplexList(row[name].ToString() + row[year].ToString()){table = table.Clone()});
}
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            foreach(var item in complexlist)
            {

                if(item.Name == row[name].ToString() + row[year].ToString())
                {
                    item.table.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
                }
            }
        }
```

now i have 8 different tables and pretty much have to do the same process again to split by type.

Is there any cleaner and less complex way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a linq solution. I haven't used DataTables in a long time, usually I convert data to DomainObjects or Models and then work with them before binding to a UI.

```
        class DomainObject
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Year { get; set; }
            public string Type { get; set; }
            public string Version { get; set; }
        }
        class GroupedDomainObject
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Year { get; set; }
            public string Type { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<string> Versions { get; set; }
        }

        private IEnumerable<GroupedDomainObject> ConvertDataTableToGroupedDomainObject(DataTable dataTable)
        {
            IEnumerable<DomainObject> complexList = dataTable.Select()  // DataTable Select turns it into an IEnumerable
                .Select(r => new DomainObject  // a linq Select turns it into your DomainObject
                {
                    Name = r["Name"].ToString(),
                    Year = Convert.ToInt16(r["Year"]),
                    Type = r["Type"].ToString(),
                    Version = r["Version"].ToString()
                });

            // now use linq GroupBy to turn it into (your 64) distinct Groups
            return complexList.GroupBy(i => new { i.Name, i.Year, i.Type }, (key, items) => new GroupedDomainObject
            {
                Name = key.Name,
                Year = key.Year,
                Type = key.Type,
                Versions = items.Select(o => o.Version)
            });

        }

        private void testConversionToGroupedDomainObject()
        {
            var mike = new DataTable();
            mike.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            mike.Columns.Add("Year", typeof(int));
            mike.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(string));
            mike.Columns.Add("Version", typeof(string));
            mike.Rows.Add("NameOne", 2019, "TypeA", "Version1");
            mike.Rows.Add("NameOne", 2018, "TypeB", "Version2");
            mike.Rows.Add("NameOne", 2018, "TypeB", "Version3");
            mike.Rows.Add("NameOne", 2018, "TypeB", "Version4");
            mike.Rows.Add("NameTwo", 2019, "TypeA", "Version1");
            mike.Rows.Add("NameTwo", 2018, "TypeB", "Version2");
            mike.Rows.Add("NameTwo", 2018, "TypeB", "Version3");
            mike.Rows.Add("NameTwo", 2018, "TypeB", "Version4");

            var result = ConvertDataTableToGroupedDomainObject(mike);

            Debug.Assert(mike.Rows.Count == result.Select(r => r.Versions).Count());
        }
```